# Erro de execução de script em python em controller do Laravel

Tags: php, python, laravel, selenium-webdriver

Atualmente meus scripts funcionam perfeitamente dentro do schedule que são executados em horas especificas dentro do cron do meu servidor.

O problema está ocorrendo quando eu tento executar o método dentro do controller, esse método basicamente usa um [**shell_exec()**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.shell-exec.php) que executa um script em python e esse retorno é o que eu trato com o Laravel.

Quando realizo a chamada dele pelo console ou pelo schedule ele funciona corretamente, porem quando chamo o metodo ou até mesmo um `\Artisan::call('schedule:teste');` ele retorna o mesmo erro dizendo que não está encontrando o geckdriver.

[image: Imagem com erro sendo chamada pelo Controller]

Quando executo ele dentro do terminal: funciona perfeitamente:
[image: Imagem sem erro dentro do terminal]

O script em Python é esse aqui:
[tesouro_direto_precos_taxa_titulo.py](https://github.com/bulfaitelo/Tesouro-Direto-Scraper/blob/master/tesouro_direto_precos_taxa_titulo.py)

Pelo que estou percebendo quando eu executo o comando dentro do controller, ele não está utilizando os path do meu sistema. a questão é porque ?

Desde já eu agradeço toda e qualquer ajuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seu webserver tem variáveis de ambiente diferentes do seu shell. Para ter uma ideia de como está o PATH do seu ambiente, você pode usar a função [getenv](http://php.net/getenv). Por exemplo:

```
echo getenv('path');
```

Para resolver o seu problema, basta usar a função [putenv](http://php.net/putenv) setando o PATH para o caminho do geckodriver antes de chamar o script.

```
putenv('path', $path_to_geckodriver);
```